# WPF 4 and .NET 4.5 class hierarchy poster

Tags: .net, wpf, poster

I'm looking for WPF **4** and .NET **4.5**   ***class hierarchy*** posters.
Somthing like [this](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/downloads/johnbowen/Images/WPF_Poster_lowres.jpg).

I searched a lot over the web without success.
Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.Net 4.5 Class Hierarchy poster is not yet released, but you might find these posters useful released recently:

- [.Net Universe poster for 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=39952)
- [What's new in .Net 4.5](http://www.heikniemi.net/hardcoded/2011/10/whats-new-in-net-framework-4-5-poster/)
- [WPF Objects Model Poster](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/615433/WPF-Objects-Model-Poster) ([Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbiy9hp9ou1mpka/WPF_OM.png))

> For getting info and learning about *all the classes in .Net 4.5*, you
>   can look at [.Net Framework Class Library on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) which gives
>   drill down info on all the classes and namespaces in .Net 4.5
>
> For getting complete info and learning *all about WPF 4.5*, you can look
>   at [Introduction to WPF in .Net 4.5 on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[image: .Net Universe Poster 2013]
[image]
[image: WPF Objects Model]

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for providing the posters above.

Comment: Dropbox link for WPF poster no longer works.  The image provided in this answer is too small to be readable.

Answer (score 3):

I know that topic is out of date but I found out [next WPF hierarchy poster](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2nyl8d7mkum4y6/WPF_Poster_new.png). I hope it can be helpful too.
[image: WPF Poster]

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, I will update it in 8 hours, for a while I`ve added with worse quality.

Comment: @SergeP The link to Dropbox is no longer working, could you please repost a valid link to the diagram? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @DonBox I has updated link, no idea why old one stopped working

Answer (score 1):

I found this, it could probably be helpful to you as well:

http://www.heikniemi.net/hardcoded/2011/10/whats-new-in-net-framework-4-5-poster/

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most up to date but it's the best I've been able to find through my efforts. [Here it is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/01/12/net-framework-3-5-namespace-poster-updated.aspx)!